# Windows auto activate method

Tags: c#, .net, windows, c#-4.0, wmi

I need a windows activate method. My code works, but it create a popup window and I don't want it.
Is there any way to activate in background without any message?

```
private void tryingActivateWindows()
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + "SLMGR -ato");
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = psi;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Comment: @SarveshMishra I tried it, but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void tryingActivateWindows()
{
    Process activateScript = new Process();
    activateScript.StartInfo.FileName = @"cscript";
    activateScript.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32\"; 
    activateScript.StartInfo.Arguments = "//B //Nologo slmgr.vbs -ato";
    activateScript.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    activateScript.Start();
    activateScript.WaitForExit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `"cscript C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs /ato"`

It will prevent the pop-up.

Comment: Thanks, this is helped me!